# java file not appearing in project

Tags: java, android

I have a project which I work on from various computers and one of these computers cannot find a java file within the folder. I have tried importing the file, rebuilding the project and cleaning the project, but the file doesnt appear at all. This is only happening on one computer. The file's name is Game.java
[Here is the project terminal, missing the game.java file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJNXq.png)

[Here is the folder containing my files, which has the game.java file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8lqU.png)

Comment: Are you missing a `package` statement?

Answer (score 0):

Right click the project, and choose "Refresh".

Answer (score 0):

If it's just a folder (and not a java or Android lib), then there is no reason for Android Studio to show you that folder in the `Android` view. You might want to switch to the `Project` view.

How to do that is described here https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/